# How to solve the error “”before all“ hook: prepare suite:”

Tags: solidity, truffle, ether

When I tested my contract, I got this error ""before all" hook: prepare suite:"

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

This is my dependencies. "truffle": "5.0.7", "web3": "1.0.0-beta.46"

Comment: Yes, go to the `before` part in your test, add a `console.log` statement after every line and find out which line is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved by updating truffle version.